# Django conditional extends with string concatenation

Tags: python, django

In a Django template I have a default base and specific *instrument*/base template.

I tried to do something like this:

```
{% extends instrument|yesno:instrument|add:"/base.html,base.html" %}
```

If the instrument exists I will extend "*instrument*/base.html" otherwise just "base.html".

This fails miserably:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist: instrum2/base.html,base.html
```

Any idea how I can sort this out?

Notes: I only have instrument passed as argument from the view. There's no way I can pass the base template as argument as well.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sorry about that. Dont know what I was thinking :P . How about sending the template in context? something like: `{% extends instrument_template|default:"base.html" %}` where the template variable is sent via context

Comment: @karthikr : I have no access to the views... It's impossible to me to pass any other parameters :(

Comment: Is instrument a constant string or it can be anything?

Comment: instrument is a string that varies, depending on the instrument. There are about 20 types.

Comment: Can you define your own filter?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is too complicated a logic to sit in the template itself, and although it may be possible with Django templates, I'd ask:

How about doing the logic in the view itself?

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    instrument = #get it from somewhere here
    kwargs['base'] = "%s/base.html" % instrument if instrument else "base.html"
    return super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Then you can just `{% extends base %}` in the template.

Comment: That's indeed a problem. If I were you, I would start with questioning that. If this is because it's in a third-party app, you can inherit it and override just that method. If the issue is administrative access (I feel bad for you if so), I'd try to either get access or have it changed by someone who can. Moving logic into the view is never a good choice in the long run.

Comment: It's administrative access... I also feel bad for me... Anyway! Thanks a lot for the help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps taking an approach something like below using the `include` tag...

```
base.html
view.html
instrument1/base.html
instrument2/base.html
```

Let's assume `view.html` is the template rendered by the view, that `base.html` is the base instrument template to inherit...and others are per instrument customization of that.

**view.html**

```
{% if instrument %}
    {% include instrument|add:'/base.html' %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'base.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

**instrument1/base.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

**instrument2/base.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```